# How to extend or "hook" Drupal Form AJAX?

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, ajax

I'm working with standard admin form, which has `'add_more'` button for one of fields.
[image: example dialog with «add more» button]
My task is to move some fields to jQuery UI Dialog just for usability. When dialog was closed I manually append it's content to form so It sends normally.
The problem appears when some core ajax is sending while some form parts are in the dialog (i.e. outside of `form` tag because jQuery UI Dialog appears in the bottom of `body`). The `'add_more'` button as example. When I click on it, the form serializes for AJAX without some inputs in the dialog.
Оh..
The jQuery Form Plugin (which used by Drupal) has option [`beforeSerialize`](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object). I think it can help me but I don't know  how I can extend Drupal.ajax.options to set something custom.

If you can recommend other ways to solve my problem or give some links to documentation about Drupal JavaScript, I will be very happy :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you, **@yvan**, for answer. Links you added are good.
But there are better documentation in source code comments. If you want to understand how it works you should look through files `includes/ajax.inc` and `misc/ajax.js`.
My problem was solved like this:

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.MyModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

        // Overwrite beforeSubmit
        Drupal.ajax['some_element'].options.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element, options) {
            // ... Some staff added to form_values
            // return false; // to prevent AJAX call if needed.
        }
        //Or you can overwrite beforeSubmit
        Drupal.ajax['some_element'].options.beforeSerialize = function (element, options) {

            // ... Some staff added to options.data
            // Also call parent function
            Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSerialize(element, options);
        }

                    //...
```

These functions are calling in [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit sad, but the JavaScript Documentation for Drupal 7 is really poor but still better than Drupal 6 :)

Well, I understand your problem and I haven't found a solution, I just can send you to some interesting pages that can help you.

First, about [Ajax Forms in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/752056) who send you also to [Ajax Framework](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) and finally look into [Example Ajax Module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example--ajax_example.module/7), maybe you'll find something that can help you.

Comment: Yes, these pages are good for understanding concepts of AJAX Forms in Drupal. But I wanted something more :)

Comment: I fount it in the Drupal documentation, [hook_ajax_render_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_ajax_render_alter/7) maybe it's can help you. One of the commands is "setting".