# Ajax Throbber Global Location

Tags: theming, ajax, javascript

How to change the ajax throbber location and make it appear in one place in the site whenever any ajax action is running.

For example I have

I want the ajax image to stop appearing in its normal location beside the ajax link or button to appear in the ajaxThrobber div mentioned above. Like Twitter new Ajax Throbber. Always appear instead of the bird logo.

Any possible answers including jQuery is welcomed.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate but [this might help](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31238/how-do-i-change-the-ajax-loading-behaviour-in-views)

Comment: I saw it before, But it dosen't solve what I am trying to do, Which is to remove all the ajax throbbers from original place and add them into one global place, I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve here, Thank u

Comment: IMHO, There is huge challenge to this as not all core and contrib use the same ajax image. I just went through this will Core, Flag and Views. All three use their own and I have to find and style each on their own.

Comment: @NigelWaters from where do you think we can start.

Comment: See http://drupal.org/node/1059674 for a point in the right direction.