# Pre and Post event on AJAX call

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

In a form, using #ajax to add a callback when a button is pressed. When the button on my form is pressed, I wish to call some JavaScript when the button is pressed and once again when the AJAX call is complete. can anyone suggest?

Comment: Is the ajax call under your control?

Comment: A similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898381/jquery-how-to-fire-certain-action-before-and-after-every-ajax-call

Comment: And this too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219706/drupal-7-fapi-ajax-and-jquery-submit-event

Comment: Yes Ajax under my control

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9920/how-to-extend-or-hook-drupal-form-ajax which even provides a working example.

Answer (score 1):

The "duplicate" I linked to above gives you almost all of your answer, but this adds the "complete" function that you asked for.

In a custom js file in your module (this assumes that your module is named `ajax_example` and that the ID of the element being clicked is `#edit-submit`):

```
Drupal.behaviors.ajax_example = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // Overwrite beforeSubmit
    Drupal.ajax['edit-submit'].options.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element, options) {
      console.log('before');
      // Add your on click code here
    }
    // Overwrite complete
    Drupal.ajax['edit-submit'].options.complete = function (form_values, element, options) {
      console.log('after');
      // Add your on complete code here
    }
  }
}
```